# Creating reference for command

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a command that creates a formatted minipage that is defined roughly like

```
\newcounter{X}
\setcounter{X}{1}
\newcommand{\assumption}[2]{
   \begin{minipage}%
     Assumption \Roman{X}: #1 \\#2%
   \end{minipage}%
   \addtocounter{X}{1}%
}
```

I'd like to be able to reference the minipage command. Preferably using `\ref`, but this isn't nescessary. Basically I would like to be able to do something like

```
\assumption{flatearth}{The earth is flat!}{It is obvious that this   
assumption is reasonable.}

From assumption \ref{assum:flatearth} it follows that it's \emph{real} 
circumference is $\infty$ and that the Victoria was capable of
superluminal velocities.
```

or just have a command like `\assref{flatearth}`. They should produce roman numerals corresponding to the counter `X`.

Apologies for the ambiguous title, I've been trying to work out what to search for, it's not so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcounter{X}
\renewcommand\theX{\Roman{X}}

\newcommand{\assumption}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{X}%
\label{assum:#1}%
   \begin{minipage}%
     Assumption \theX: #1 \\#2%
   \end{minipage}%

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I want, there is still one little bit wrong with it. The output from \ref{assum:whatever} is in Arabic not Roman numerals - is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: are you sure you ran latex again after adding the 
\renewcommand\theX{\Roman{X}}

Comment: A couple of times. I will do it a few more. Does it require the command \theX or \the<countername>? The latter it seems. Works now! Thanks.

Comment: once should be enough, Make a complete document "MWE"  that shows the problem

Comment: I thought your countername _was_ X ??

Comment: That was a very reasonable thing to think. I was something more like `veryverylongnamethatIdontwanttotypeoverandoveragain` so I just called it X. I thought it would be very odd for latex to look for a reference for something defined by \the<countername>, seems once again, that latex is just very very strange.

Comment: \thecountername isn't really for references it defines how that counter is printed. references just happen to use the default print format of the counter by default